# iOS 7.1 navigationBar title touch

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can you detect the touch of the navigationBar title in iOS 7.   The code below worked great prior to iOS 7 but no longer is the touch detected.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

thanks,

Greg

Comment: Works with iOS 7 but not 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the description of `self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1]`? (Just NSLog it).

The same code works good for me:

```
UIView *viewWithTitleLabel = self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1];
viewWithTitleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureOccured:)];
[viewWithTitleLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

When do you call your code? Seems to be that "subviews[1]" - is not your desired view.

Comment: in the viewdidload.     description of subview object 1 == <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0x10af5fcc0; frame = (8 12; 12.5 20.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10af7f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10af0ebd0>>

Comment: Please, print the self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1]

Comment: <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0x10af5fcc0; frame = (8 12; 12.5 20.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10af7f960>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10af0ebd0>>

Comment: So, its not the same that I've got. 
   Mine is (<UINavigationItemView: 0x11c7b6e0; frame = (117.5 8; 85 27); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd9cd580>; layer = <CALayer: 0x11c7b7c0>>
).
As you see iOS7 navigation bar has more subviews than iOS6 one. I can suggest to set navigationItem.titleView as UIView with UILabel as a subview and add UIGestureRecognizer to this titleView.
This will 100% guarantee that gesture will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
TapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

NSInteger objIndex = 1;
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.1f) objIndex = 2;

[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:objIndex] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:objIndex] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 (and probably 7), the title object has the private class `UINavigationItemView` that you can check for and then apply your gesture recognition code more judiciously, rather than blindly using array indices.

```c
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemView")] &&
        ![view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationItemButtonView")])
    {
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectorGoesHere:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        break;
    }
}
```

Whether or not this will pass app review is another question – one that I couldn't answer.